# Не работает часть сайта из за php кода

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Не работает часть сайта из за php кода на хостинге 000webhost.com . Удалил код php из файла, и все работает. На локальном сервере, все работает как часики. А сдесь не работает.

```css
body {
 background-image: url(img/bananas.png);
 margin:0;
}

h1{
 color:black;
 background-color:yellow;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:20px;
 font-style: italic;
}

.header_top {
 background-color:black;
 height:8px;
 position: relative;
 top:23px;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:50px;
}

.header_bottom {
 background-color:black;
 height:8px;
 position: relative;
 top:-23px;
 margin-left:40px;
 margin-right:40px;
 border-radius:10px;
}

.box {
 background-color:yellow;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:2px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 margin-left:11px;
 margin-right:11px;
 margin-top:2px;
 
}
.box_out {
 border:2px solid black;
 border-radius:10px;
 height:100px;
 margin-left:9px;
 margin-right:9px;
 margin-top:-102px;
 
}

.bottom{
  padding:0 12px;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}

.box_left {
 background-color:yellow;
 height:205px;
 width: 47%;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:2px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.box_left_out {
 border:2px solid black;
 border-radius:10px;
 height:205px;
 width:47%;
 margin-top:-207px;
  
 position:relative;
    right:2px;
}
    
.box_right {
 background-color:yellow;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:2px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 width: 47%;
 height: 205px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: -207px;
}
.box_right_out {
 border:2px solid black;
 border-radius:10px;
    height:205px;
 width: 47%;
 margin-left:100px;
 float: right;
 margin-top:-209px;
    position:relative;
    left:2px;
}
.bl-status {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 11px;
    max-height: 100%;  
}


.connect {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.noconnect {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<html>
<body>

<div class="bl-status">
  <span align="left" class="status">Server status:</span>
  <?php
  ini_set('display_errors','off');
  error_reporting('E_ALL');

  $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','user_id','password','sql_iq');
  if ($connection == false) 
  {
  echo '<div align="left" class="noconnect"></div>';
  }

  if ($connection == true) 
  {
     echo '<div align="left" class="connect"></div>';
  }
  ?>
</div>


<div align="center" class="header_top"></div>

<div align="center" class="osnova">
  <h1>32131</h1>
</div>
  
<div align="center" class="header_bottom"></div>

<div aling="center" class="box"></div>
<div aling="center" class="box_out"></div>

<div class="bottom">
<div aling="left" class="box_left"></div>
<div aling="left" class="box_left_out"></div>

<div align="right" class="box_right"></div>
<div align="right" class="box_right_out"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А текст ошибки какой?

Comment: ёё нету, просто отображается текст - Server Satatus, и фон. И все, блоки, тексты и сам индикатор статуса сервера не работает.

Comment: А на хостинге вообще подключена возможность использования php?

Comment: И если подключено, то ini_set('display_errors','on'); включите

Comment: Да, конечно. phpMyAdmin. Раньше работал php код (другой код), а сейчас не понимаю почему нету половины сайта.

Comment: Ошибки php нету, все работает, и на локальном сервере все работает. Но не отображается элементы сайта кроме фона и одного текста.

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок, может что и увидите

Comment: Уже включал, не работает. Я все проверил сначала на своем сервере (OpenServer). Закончил роботу и захотел выкласть на хостинг. Вот как должно быть, и как оно есть https://imgur.com/a/CYEKsCD

Comment: ну тут хрустального шара нет либо текст ошибки либо кусок лога где он есть

Comment: версия php совпадает ?

Comment: Может потому что вы подключаетесь к localhost на хостинге?)

Comment: @AntonKucenko имя базы и логин как раз похожи на выданные хостером

Comment: @MishaNikolov смотрите, спотыкается на куске php, если б не было поддержки php, то вывелся бы ваш код. Значит ошибка в вашем коде. Не выдает ничего в тексте, значит ищите в логах сервера

Comment: Ок,  а бд? localhost

Comment: @AntonKucenko это нормальное явление на хостингах. В любом случае надо найти текст ошибки

Comment: Ставлю на то, что на хостинге deprecated для устаревшей функции `mysql_connect` и надо использовать либо `pdo_mysql` либо `mysqli`

Comment: Проверьте ошибки какие появляются...Возможно поймете если будут ошибки.Но проще не совмещать php и html как вы делаете.Проще сделать файл с расширением .php и туда уже пихать html и php...

Answer (score 3):

Ты используешь `mysql` что уже устарело в php.Поэтому тебе надо перейти к использованию `mysqli` или `PDO`

Попробуй так:

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','user_id','password','sql_iq');
```

Если не решится проблема,сообщи тут. Мне тоже интересно стало зачем так.

Comment: Спасибо, выручил. Спасибо за помощь.